# Endless process of packaging iOS mobile app in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: ios, mobile, air, flash-builder

I built a iOS apps dozens of times with Flash Builder and always it was a long time (5-10 minutes), but always successful. In the new project does not stop the process of packaging for 30-45 minutes and then I can not wait more. After a half hour of packaging, hourglass is still going, and packaging is at 0%. If I pack this app for Android is all fine.

Judging by the comments this is a common problem.

There are no errors or warnings. I checked the certificates and provisions in a new empty project and its work fine.

How can I track or see logs of the progress of packaging and where to look for errors?

Comment: what have you changed after the last successful packaging? any added components/native extensions etc?

Comment: Which comments are you referring too? I haven't heard of this problem before and fortunately haven't experienced it either.

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu I can build other iOS projects as usual. Is not affected.

Comment: @Al_Birdy For example http://forums.adobe.com/message/4363196

Comment: What do you mean with "is not affected"? And how about the native extensions or libraries as asked before?

Comment: This applied to the first question. Of course, there are many libraries. I use Robotlegs, assets in swc, etc. But do you suggest not to use its? How to verify that the problem in the libs? Moreover, if I use debug mode, all normal builds, and run on a real device (fast mode), but when used in standard debug mode then endless packaging again.

Comment: I also had a problems when I added some native extensions, that's why I've asked..

Comment: I do not suggest not to use them, I was merely suggesting checking if they are the cause for your issue. The question from the very first comment remains, did you ADD any components/ANEs/libraries recently?

Comment: I apologize if I did not put it clearly. I adapt a flash web project (for browser) for mobile devices. Everything works fine on the FB 4.6 emulators, works fine on real devices in debug mode, perfectly built for Android, but it is not packaging for iOS. ANE is not used. Only a few libraries, from which I have almost everything off (commented out code fragments where they are required). Remained almost two - Robotlegs swc and Assets.swc (various graphic elements created in Flash IDE). Without them I can not use the project. The problem remains.

Comment: I made a screenshot of the task manager during packaging project http://clip2net.com/s/2hvRL Seen that run Java and it strongly loads the CPU. But nothing happens. Maybe something to update Java?

Comment: Apart from updating Java (which I don't see as the cause for this issue tbh), I'd probably update Robotlegs as well. I understand that you cannot exclude Robotlegs and your assets library from your project, but a simple sample project that utilises both of these libraries should reveal whether they cause the issue you're experiencing.